# .htaccess file copied from live server partially not working on local

Tags: .htaccess

I just copied all of my web files to my pc including the .htaccess file. And now I run it on XAMPP. I got this problem, this .htaccess file:

```
DirectoryIndex otherindex.php //<<--this line works, it changes my index.

//but the rest is not: I need to redirecting all request (except existing dir/file) to index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
```

I have no idea why does it work on live server, but not on my XAMPP. How can I get it work on both ? Any help please?

**update:**
I check my `httpd.conf` and get this uncommented:

`LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`

Note: I move my default htdocs folder to other location.

Comment: Can you post the settings of your site's .conf file? Particularly what is between the <VirtualHost...> tags.

Comment: no such things, this is just fresh instal of XAMPP.

Comment: Is line `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` a comment in you *httpd.conf* file? It seems .htacces files are allowed as the first directive works, but not `mod_rewrite`. On the other hand, is there an error, the rule is not used, what's exactly the problem?

Comment: @faa no it is not a comment;  the problem is the rule is not working, but in my live server it is. I think there is a different configuration between my XAMPP and my live-server, but I have no idea what it is.

Comment: Where is the .htccess file and where is DocumentRoot pointing to in your local server?

Comment: @faa `.htaccess` in `D:/htdocs/mysite` and `DocumentRoot` pointing to `D:/htdocs`, `ServerRoot` : `C:xampp/apache/bin` on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do is make sure that you have the rewrite module enabled in Apache. Next I would check that you have Apache configured to allow Rewrite conditions in .htaccess files. For security reasons most htaccess features are blocked by default.

To check for the second problem, you can search your `httpd.conf` for `AllowOverride None`. If you find that, change it to `AllowOverride All`. You can also enable this in your site's .conf file.

Comment: I changed all `AllowOverride` to all, but doesn't make it yet. :(

Comment: Did you restart Apache after you saved your changes? The changes don't take effect until it's been restarted.

Comment: yes, I restarted it. Note that I move default htdocs folder to other location, could it be the cause ?